# Magnific Popup Lightbox Will Launch when Hand-coded but Not When Converting to WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, magnific-popup

Using Magnific Popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#known_issues), I have SUCCESSFULLY created a lightbox image when writing it by hand in a text editor.  My successful code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/magnific-popup.css">

</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

   <div>
      <a href="https://bourassarehab.com/files/stacks_image_85.jpg" title="Test caption 1" class="image-link">Show img 1</a>
      <a href="https://bourassarehab.com/files/stacks_image_126.jpg" title="Test caption" class="image-link">Show img 2</a>
   </div>

   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
   <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $('div').magnificPopup({
         type: 'image',
         delegate: 'a',

         gallery:{enabled:true},
         callbacks: {

            buildControls: function() {
               // re-appends controls inside the main container
               this.contentContainer.append(this.arrowLeft.add(this.arrowRight));
            }

         }
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when converting the template to a WordPress theme, the popup/lightbox will not initialize.  Instead of the image loading up in a lightbox/popup, it loads as a standalone image in the browser window.  I believe I have enqueued all styles and scripts correctly.  Here is my WordPress source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

   <?php
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lime_enqueue_scripts' );
   function lime_enqueue_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
      wp_enqueue_style('flat-ui', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/frameworks/flat-ui/css/flat-ui.css');
      wp_enqueue_style('magnific-popup-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/helpers/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css');
      wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
      wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
      wp_enqueue_script('magnific-popup-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/helpers/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array('jquery'));
   } ?>

   <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

   <div>
      <a href="https://bourassarehab.com/files/stacks_image_85.jpg" title="Test caption 1" class="image-link">Show img 1</a>
      <a href="https://bourassarehab.com/files/stacks_image_126.jpg" title="Test caption" class="image-link">Show img 2</a>
   </div>

   <?php wp_footer(); ?>
   <script>
   $('div').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      delegate: 'a',

      gallery:{enabled:true},
      callbacks: {

         buildControls: function() {
            // re-appends controls inside the main container
            this.contentContainer.append(this.arrowLeft.add(this.arrowRight));
         }

      }
   });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my WordPress compiled code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>Prairie Garden Seeds</title>


   <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css-css'  href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flat-ui-css'  href='http://macbook.local:5757/wp-content/themes/prairie-garden-seeds/frameworks/flat-ui/css/flat-ui.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='magnific-popup-css-css'  href='http://macbook.local:5757/wp-content/themes/prairie-garden-seeds/assets/helpers/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='styles-css'  href='http://macbook.local:5757/wp-content/themes/prairie-garden-seeds/style.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook.local:5757/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook.local:5757/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://macbook.local:5757/wp-content/themes/prairie-garden-seeds/assets/helpers/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://macbook.local:5757/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://macbook.local:5757/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

</head>
<body>

   <div>
      <a href="https://bourassarehab.com/files/stacks_image_85.jpg" title="Test caption 1" class="image-link">Show img 1</a>
      <a href="https://bourassarehab.com/files/stacks_image_126.jpg" title="Test caption" class="image-link">Show img 2</a>
   </div>

      <script>
   $('div').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      delegate: 'a',

      gallery:{enabled:true},
      callbacks: {

         buildControls: function() {
            // re-appends controls inside the main container
            this.contentContainer.append(this.arrowLeft.add(this.arrowRight));
         }

      }
   });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine from the outside. No errors in the JS console?

Comment: Console reports error:
uncaught type error - undefined is not a function
$('div').magnificPopup({

Comment: Looks like the library isn't loading. Are you sure http://macbook.local:5757/wp-content/themes/prairie-garden-seeds/assets/helpers/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?ver=3.9.1 is working? You can also check the Net tab in Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listener was not working because WordPress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode, therefore using $ did not work.  To solve do either of the following:

1. Wrap your jQuery in a no-conflict wrapper

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(#somefunction) ...
   });

or

change all instances of $ to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There is WordPress plugin: Andora Lightbox. Grid gallery with lightbox. It uses Magnific Popup script.

Check it on WordPress plugins site: http://wordpress.org/plugins/andora-lightbox/

Comment: Looks like a great plugin, however I am wanting to attach the images to the already existing post and use get_post_meta(). Thanks though.